# ASP.NET Core Web Api controller end points are all returning 404 error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web Api project that 9 ApiControllers with several endpoints per controller.
Each controller endpoint communicates with a Unit of Work / Repository pattern built on Dapper ORM.

All controllers class headers look like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
...
```

This Api communicates with a Xamarin Android project to send and receive data.

This solution has been working very well since the early spring.
I made a couple changes to the repository layer to modify a query, and the code compiles properly. When I run the application now in both localhost and at a web host server, ALL endpoints tested from Postman return a 404 error.
Nothing was changed in Nuget packages, appsettings.json or launchsettings.json.

I have been trying to figure this out for 2 days and really need some help.
I have reviewed all of related posts that I can locate that has core but I have not seen a match to my problem.

What other info can I provide?

Ryan

UPDATE 1
Here is a sample method that gets called to authenticate a user:
This url would be called like 'https://localhost:44365/api/auth/authenticate'

```
[HttpPost("authenticate")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Login>> Authenticate([FromBody] Login login)
        {
            // login will come in from the device with basic auth
            string token = string.Empty;
            string username = login.UserName;
            string password = login.Password;
            int product = login.Product;
            string deviceName = login.DeviceName;
            try
            {
                bool isAuth = await _unitOfWork.Logins.GetAuthenticateUser(username, password, product);
                if(isAuth == false)
                {
                    return StatusCode(401);
                }

                //check for preference record
                bool exists = await _unitOfWork.Sessions.CheckForDevice(deviceName, product);
                if(!exists)
                {
                    // auto add the device
                    Prefs prefs = new Prefs();
                    SecurityUser user = await _unitOfWork.Logins.GetUserInfo(username, product);
                    prefs.deviceName = deviceName;
                    prefs.product = product;
                    prefs.facilityId = user.facID;
                    prefs.addedBy = username;
                    prefs.active = true;
                    prefs.timeout = "480";
                    int result = await _unitOfWork.Sessions.AddDevice(prefs, product);
                }

                Jwt j = new Jwt(_unitOfWork);
                try
                {
                    login.Token = j.CreateToken(username, deviceName, product);
                    SessionModel session = new SessionModel();
                    session.SessionStart = DateTime.Now;
                    login.SessionStart = session.SessionStart;
                    session.UserName = username;
                    session.Token = login.Token;
                    await _unitOfWork.Sessions.AddSession(session, product);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //delete session if there is jwt error
                    await _unitOfWork.Sessions.DeleteAsyncByUserName(username, product);
                    var msg = $"Error message from create token - Inner Exception: {ex.InnerException} Exception Message: {ex.Message} Source: {ex.Source}";
                    login.Message = msg;
                    login.UserName = String.Empty;
                    login.Password = String.Empty;
                    //return login object with message 
                    return login;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var msg = $"Error message from Header Auth decode - Inner Exception: {ex.InnerException} Exception Message: {ex.Message} Source: {ex.Source}";
                login.Message = msg;
                login.UserName = String.Empty;
                login.Password = String.Empty;
                return login;
            }
            //return login obj with token, msg, session datetime
            login.UserName = String.Empty;
            login.Password = String.Empty;
            return login;
        }
```

Update 2
My biggest challenge here is figuring out why the controller endpoints are suddenly returning 404 after 5 months and no modification to the controller code.

Update 3
The Startup Configure method

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

        }
```

Comment: Can you show an action method and example of url you call?

Comment: I added an action method

Comment: [Route("api/[controller]")] to [Route("api/[controller]/[action]") then your url will be localhost:xxx/api/auth/authenticate]  And ensure postman is set to POST not GET sometimes simple things are missed.

Comment: Thank you. I have verified all of the points you gave.

Comment: Just to confirm it is ok now?

Comment: No not even close. All endpoints still return 404

Comment: Have you tried simply changing the port?  Sometimes I found projects will just not work on given port for some reason and you can change iis express port and then try

Comment: Make sure your api is not running on different port.

Comment: when I run the Api locally it runs localhost:44365 and I test the same port while calling the endpoints from Postman.

Comment: is this only happens when running on localhost?

Comment: no it happens when deployed to Winhost as well.

Comment: given the nature of the changes you suggest, I'm strongly suspicious that the 404 is actually because the controller can't load... i.e. some dependency in the constructor isn't working right, isn't available, something.

Comment: Hmm, thanks Reginald, I am going to look down that hole

Comment: Hi @Ryan, can you post the code about the `Startup.Configure` method? The issue might relate the routing configuration.

Comment: Code doesn't just "stop working". Roll back to the version that worked, then compare the non-working to the working.

Comment: @ZhiLv I posted the Startup.Configure

Answer (score 1):

I discovered in the appsettings.json file, there was a C# style comment in the json. Removing that comment appears to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a WebAPI hosted on Azure. I did an upgrade on the NuGET Packages and did a migration to OData Version 8. This suddenly made my queries case sensitive in the filters.
Lets say I have a field "State" in my database and I query this with "https://localhost:5555/Adresses?$filter=state eq 'NY'" then is gives me an error because I query for state and not for State.
Other thing could be that, in case you use API Management on Azure, that you Swagger file is broken and the links in the API management as not there.
Maybe this helps you.

Comment: Interesting. I will do an update on my Nuget and check my swagger file

Comment: i forced a restore on my nuget packages and that did not change the outcome of more 404 errors